# Why Jakarta EE specifications from Jakarta ee web site are empty?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I would like to understand why some Jakarta EE specifications are empty.
For example for [Jakarta Annotations](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/1.3/) specifications is composed by a Disclaimers and a quick description (3 lines), however there is [Javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/1.3/apidocs/).
When JCP was in charge of J2EE speficiations it was more documented, still taking example on [annotations specifications](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/caj-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/). When I read [Jakarta EE 8 plateform specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/platform-spec-8.pdf) I find more informations but this is still lower them JCP. 
Then I finish to find specifications in the [github account of the Eclipse EE4J](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j) with lot of details (remark this is not easy to find a particular specifications with the hudge number of repositories).
I would like to know if some specifications coming from jakarta ee web site are empty because these is exactly the sames of J2EE or Eclipse decide to prefer javadoc support and Why there is no link to github specification  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a lot of discussion in the [jakarta.ee-community mailing list](https://www.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jakarta.ee-community) about this.
What I can say from what I know is that some specs were not entirely transferred yet.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/jakartaee/specifications/issues/119) on JakartaEE Specifications GitHub addressing this.